# 3G dongle switch to modem after the network interfaces loaded

Tags: linux, networking, ppp, pppd, usb-modeswitch

I have a Raspberry Pi with a 3G Dongle connected. I want to automatically switch in modem mode + load the ppp interface **during the boot**.

I use `usb_modeswitch` to automatically switch in modem mode during the boot and it works.

And wvdial is well managed if it launches like it after the boot: `sudo wvdial ppp0`. I can ping the world! (OK just IPs and domains)

The issue is the interfaces network are loaded before the modem switch in boot process... As you can see in the `syslog` file (check dates and hours):

```
Feb 11 19:18:07 raspberrypi logger: /etc/ppp/wait-dialup-hardware: ERROR timeout waiting for required device /dev/gsmmodem

Feb 11 19:18:09 raspberrypi logger: usb_modeswitch: switched to 05c6:6000 on 001/005
```

I have tried [this solution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/3G_and_GPRS_modems_with_pppd#Patch_for_modem_availability_after_booting) to force to wait the dialup hardware. Waiting the /dev/gsmmodem is mounted but it doesn't work.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto ppp0
   iface ppp0 inet wvdial
   provider ppp0
   pre-up echo "3G dongle starting..."
   pre-up /etc/ppp/wait-dialup-hardware gsmmodem 30
   post-up echo "3G (ppp0) is online"
```

My `/etc/ppp/wait-dialup-hardware` file:

```
#!/bin/sh  

INTERFACE="/dev/$1"
MAX_SECONDS_TIMEOUT=$2

dsec=$(( MAX_SECONDS_TIMEOUT * 10 ))
retry=0 
while [ "$retry" -le "$dsec" ]; do
   if [ -c ${INTERFACE} ]; then
      echo "$0: OK existing required device ${INTERFACE} (in $((retry / 10)).$((100 * (retry % 10) / 10)) seconds)"
      logger "$0: OK existing required device ${INTERFACE} (in $((retry / 10)).$((100 * (retry % 10) / 10)) seconds)"
      break
   else
      sleep 0.1
   fi
   retry=$(( retry + 1))
done
if [ ! -c ${INTERFACE} ]; then
    echo "$0: ERROR timeout waiting for required device ${INTERFACE}"
    logger "$0: ERROR timeout waiting for required device ${INTERFACE}"
    exit 1
fi
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: did you tried load use_modeswitch at interface pre-up ?

Comment: Yes I tried but doesn't work. I think because USB ports are not ready?! 
      Feb 13 14:14:34 raspberrypi networking[218]: Configuring network interfaces...Look for target devices ...
      Feb 13 14:14:34 raspberrypi networking[218]: No devices in target mode or class found
      Feb 13 14:14:34 raspberrypi networking[218]: Look for default devices ...
      Feb 13 14:14:34 raspberrypi networking[218]: No devices in default mode found. Nothing to do. Bye!